# Applications of the Atiyah-Patodi-Singer eta-function $\eta(s)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-operators, index-theory

The eta function of a differential operator was used by Atiyah, Patodi and Singer to derive their famous index theorem, and is given by

$$
\eta(s)=\sum_{\lambda\neq 0}(\mathrm{sign}\lambda)|\lambda|^{-s},
$$

where the sum goes over the nonzero eigenvalues of the operator. The limit $\lim_{s\to 0}\eta(s)$ is the eta invariant that appears in the index theorem itself.

My question is: are there known applications for the eta function evaluated at other values of $s$ ?

Comment: Let's assume we're talking about the spinor Dirac operator associated to a Riemannian spin manifold.  If you multiply the Riemannian metric by some constant then the eigenvalues of the Dirac operator scale by the same constant, and thus the value of the eta function at $s \neq 0$ changes.  So the value at $s = 0$ is the only one we can expect to be an interesting global invariant (though if memory serves it is not actually invariant under all isometries).

Comment: @PaulSiegel Thank you for your comment, I am aware of the scaling property. I'm not exclusively interested in global invariants, any potential application would be great to hear about.

Comment: The point of this observation is that it limits the sort of applications that one can hope for.  $\eta(0)$ has interesting applications because it solves an index problem on manifolds with boundary; $\eta(s)$ can't solve any sort of index problem because it depends too sensitively on the metric.  This doesn't rigorously prove that $\eta(s)$ is uninteresting - that's why I left this as a comment instead of an answer - but I don't see much cause for optimism.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! This link states that $\eta(1)$ of a Dirac operator is its propagator: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/eta+invariant However, I was not able to find more than this.